# Why list item is zero?

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have a list which contains following items:

> Bundled/releases/US---NL
>   Bundled/releases/UK---US

I want  search for substring ("US" or "UK") in list item.

```
var testVar = (from r in ghh
    where (r.Substring(r.LastIndexOf('/') + 1, 
                       (r.Length - (r.IndexOf("---")    + 3)))) == "US"
    select r).ToList();

if ( testVar != null)
{
    //print item is present
}
```

(`ghh` is list name)

But `testVar` is always showing `null`. Why?

Comment: With this kind of problem simply debug to find out what's not working/having the expected value.

Comment: @Keyser Can We debug lambda expression?

Comment: @Prateek You can debug stuff that's executed. So yes, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another way:

```
testVar.Where(x => {
    var country = x.Split('/').Last()
              .Split(new[] { "---" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .First();

    return country == "US" || country == "UK";
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use (assuming the list is simply a list of string):

```
 var items = (from r in ghh where r.Contains("UK") || r.Contains("US") select r).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no circumstances where `testVar` would be `null` .

Here is some code to illustrate this. Be sure to activate the Output view before running... 
View -> Output

The only thing that could happen is that the linq query is executed later and you get a null exception because your ghh was null at the point the linq tried to query it. Linq does not nescessarily execute instantly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CallAsExpected();
            CallWithNull();
            CallNoHits();
            Console.WriteLine("Look at Debug Output");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void CallNoHits()
        {
            TryCall(new List<string> {
                "UK foo",
                "DE bar"
            });
        }

        private static void CallWithNull()
        {
            TryCall(null);
        }

        private static void CallAsExpected()
        {
            TryCall(new List<string> {
                "US woohooo",
                "UK foo",
                "DE bar",
                "US second",
                "US third"
            });
        }

        private static void TryCall(List<String> ghh)
        {
            try
            {
                TestMethod(ghh);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        private static void TestMethod(List<String> ghh)
        {
            if (ghh == null) Debug.WriteLine("ghh was null");

            var testVar = (from r in ghh
                           where (r.Contains("US"))
                           select r);

            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Items Found: {0}", testVar.Count()));

            if (testVar == null) Debug.WriteLine("testVar was null");

            foreach (String item in testVar)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```